# Read all lines from file to a array

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

How can I read multiple lines (approximately 5000 lines) from a text file and store all of them in a single string array?
i already have some of the code running smooth, but it doesn't work the way its supposed to. I only get the last line of the file stored in the array.

```
  int main(){
   int n;
   char line[401];
   char string[10000];
   fr = fopen ("fila1b.txt", "rt");
   while(fgets(line, 400, fr) != NULL){
     strcat(string, line);
   }
   fclose(fr);
   printf("%s\n", string );
  }
```

EDIT: I updated the code with some changes. Now i'm using the strcat function to insert the contents of the line got by fgets to the original string array. It is working, apparently. But when i print the 'string', it only prints the first 300 lines and then it gives me Segmentation fault.

Comment: Each call to `gets` could overwrite the contents of `line`.

Comment: Well, *something* needs to go in the body of that `while` loop... perhaps the code that puts the line's contents into the array?

Comment: There is no array for the lines and all code is missing. This is not a "write my code" site. What have you got, what is your **specific** problem?

Comment: You are reading each line into a single array, the same array each time. Sometimes that is called a `string` when the array is zero-terminated, but C does not have a string type. You either need a 2-D array (which might break a local variable, and is wasteful of memory when the inputs have different lengths), or an array of pointers, which you assign with `strdup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to just slurp all the characters with `read` or `fread`:

```
#define MIN_CHUNK_SIZE (1024)

char *read_file(FILE *f) {
  size_t n_read_total = 0;
  size_t buf_size = MIN_CHUNK_SIZE + 1; // Allow space for nul terminator.
  char *buf = safe_malloc(buf_size);
  size_t n_avail;
  do {
    n_avail = buf_size - n_read_total - 1;
    if (n_avail < MIN_CHUNK_SIZE) {
      // Double the buffer size.
      n_avail += buf_size;
      buf_size += buf_size;
      buf = safe_realloc(buf, buf_size);
    }
    size_t n_read = fread(buf + n_read_total, 1, n_avail, f);
    n_read_total += n_read;
  } while (n_read == n_avail);
  buf[n_read_total] = '\0';
  return safe_realloc(buf, n_read_total + 1);
}
```